# How can i change the background color of contextual action bar and underline?

Tags: android

want to change the color of contextual action bar from black to another color and also want to change the color of underline pink line .
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcSL9.png

Answer (score 0):

You can change CAB background and underline colors by adding this line in your activity style:

```
<item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/contextual_action_bar_background</item>
```

contextual_action_bar_background.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="-2dp" android:left="-2dp" android:right="-2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/action_bar"/>
        <stroke android:color="@color/title_blue" android:width="2dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```